# Commenting results in a ratio scale

Tags: statistics, self-learning, descriptive-statistics

Consider the following plot:

[image]

Is it mathematically correct if I say *`blue` is 50% lower than `red`*. Because from the plot it appears so, but what confuses me here is the scale in the `y` axis. So there `blue` appears to be ~10% lower than `red`.

In a plot where a metric is given as a ratio in the `y` axis. Can you use ratios again to explain the difference between observed variables. If so, should you comply to the values shown in the `y` axis, or can one explain the difference with relative ratios for the variables?

EDIT: to avoid confusion -- `x` axis shows just categorical variables. lets say `method1`, and `method2`.

Comment: Consider, e.g. that they are profit %. It is correct to say that blue is approx 50%  lower than red. Approx 10% is the *absolute* difference by which it is lower. I didn't understand how x-axis comes into this particular example !

Comment: x axis shows just categorical variables. lets say method1, and method2

Comment: Yea, that's why the x-axis is irrelevant here. The ratio scale is only for the y-axis, and you can compute either the absolute difference or (*since it is a ratio scale*) the % difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is always some confusion when talking about these things, I always get annoyed how the press seem to always make a mess.

If I sell 20 cars yesterday and 10 cars today, then the sale today is $50\%$ lower than the sale yesterday. I also sold $10$ fewer cars than yesterday. Therefore:

- The absolute difference is $10$ **cars**
- The relative difference is $50$ **percent**

Similarly, if, for example, the air humidity today is $10\%$ and it was $20\%$ yesterday, the humidity level is $50\%$ lower, than yesterday, and it is lower by $10\%$ (of humidity) compared to yesterday.

- The absolute difference is $10$ **humidity percentages**
- The relative difference is $50$ **percent**

Comment: *If I sell 20 cars **today** and 10 cars **tommorow**, then the sale **today** is 50% lower than the sale **yesterday*** --- creates ambiguity. maybe using day `x` and day `x+1` would be clearer. otherwise thanks for the answer...

Comment: @KristofTak Thanks. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The *absolute difference* by which the blue is lower is $\approx$ 10%

The *% difference* by which the blue is lower is $\approx$ 50%

Please note that we can compute a % difference only for  a ratio scale.

To summarize, for this ratio scale, taking the base figures to be red,

*Absolute difference = blue - red*

*% difference* = $\dfrac{blue - red}{red}\times 100$